# Fancybox 2, images and video in same gallery with thumbnails

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

Using **FANCYBOX 2**, I'd like to have images and youtube embeds in the same gallery.

Having the url of the image as the href value works fine for images, but my issue is that I don't know what value to assign the video objects for them to open as iframe videos.

Comment: I guess this is what you want : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful --> 6. Move navigation arrows outside -->Only for type "iframe" (it would be always nice if people take time to read the documentation and look at the existing examples)

Comment: It's not about getting the navigation arrows to work, it's about getting fancybox to play a youtube embed (iframe) in the same gallery as images. It's being accomplished here: http://jsfiddle.net/4pAQz/1/, but this is the old version of fancybox and I'm using version 2 to allow thumbnails. How can I combine both?

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution…

1. add this class to the link element: fancybox.iframe
2. assign the element's href a value of: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR_VIDEO_ID_HERE?autoplay=1

Comment: Exactly as in http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful --> 6. Move navigation arrows outside -->Only for type "iframe" ... this is what I meant in my previous comment : if you would have followed the (jsfiddle) link you would have seen the code you needed for that gallery.